# 301 Redirect Not Working with "+" Sign

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to 301 redirect the following URL

> www.domain.com/Gallery2/v/South/Actress/Ritu+Kaur+Actress+Photos

to

> www.domain.com/gallery/ritu-kaur.html

I tried the following, but not worked,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^Gallery2\/v\/South\/Actress\/Ritu\+Kaur\+Actress\+Photos\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.indiancinemagallery\.com\/gallery\/ritu\-kaur\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Please advise

Comment: This should have worked. Is this your only .htaccess file?

Comment: No, this one is in my root directory for the newly created cms. Another one is located at the Gallery2 folder which has a gallery2(free gallery script) installation. i want to redirect some important URL's to my new cms such as the one given in the question. please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in your `Gallery2/.htaccess` **before any other rewrite rule**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^v/South/Actress/Ritu\+Kaur\+Actress\+Photos/?$ http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/ritu-kaur.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Wow, thank u so much. It worked fine. I have around 50 such links to be redirected, should i add them below the rewrite mentioned above ? Is there any limit for adding rewrites in htaccess ?

Comment: No 50 is totally fine, its not a lot for mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` signs will probably get canonicalized to spaces, try replacing them with spaces instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^Gallery2/v/South/Actress/Ritu\ Kaur\ Actress\ Photos/$ http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/ritu-kaur.html [L,R=301]
```

The URI is decoded before being put through matching against regex in `RewriteRule`'s, so unless your url had encoded `+` signs, then they'll get decoded to spaces instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same but no luck. Actually the URL is generated by Gallery2 using mod rewrite and am trying to redirect that URL to the second one.